# Sqlite3 trigger with UPSERT

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I'm using sqlite3 on my Rails project and I need to create a trigger that automatically inserts into the table when another referencing table is updated.
For example, I have 2 tables **Breakdown** and **Total**, schemas for each table are as below.
**Breakdown**

```
Date TEXT NOT NULL,
Amount DECIMAL NOT NULL
```

**Total**

```
Date TEXT NOT NULL,
Daily_Total DECIMAL NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Date) REFERENCES Breakdown(Date)
```

Then, below is my trigger creation.

```
        CREATE TRIGGER update_sum AFTER INSERT ON Breakdown
   ...> BEGIN
   ...> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Total (Date, Daily_Total)
   ...> VALUES (Breakdown.Date,
   ...> (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Breakdown WHERE Date = Total.Date));
   ...> END;
```

So, my idea is when I insert into **Breakdown** table as `**INSERT INTO Breakdown VALUES (Date('now'),19.99);**` then **Total** table gets updated by either inserting or update.

However, when I insert into Breakdown table, I get an error saying **Error: no such column: Breakdown.Date**

Can anyone direct me to the point where I'm doing wrong, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* access the values of the row that caused the trigger to trigger, but that 'table' [is called `NEW`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
INSERT ... VALUES(NEW.Date, (SELECT SUM... WHERE Date = NEW.Date));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I wanted! But, can I get little bit more explanation or documentation that I can read why are we using NEW rather than the actual table name?